# Layer conv2d_3 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor

Tags: keras, image-recognition, autoencoder

hi I am building a image classifier for one-class classification in which i've used autoencoder while running this model I am getting this error (ValueError: Layer conv2d_3 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: . Full input: [(128, 128, 3)]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.)

```
num_of_samples = img_data.shape[0]
labels = np.ones((num_of_samples,),dtype='int64')



labels[0:376]=0 
names = ['cat']

Y = np_utils.to_categorical(labels, num_class)
input_shape=img_data[0].shape

x,y = shuffle(img_data,Y, random_state=2)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)

x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_shape)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

# at this point the representation is (4, 4, 8) i.e. 128-dimensional

x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_shape, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')


autoencoder.fit(X_train, X_train,
            epochs=50,
            batch_size=32,
            shuffle=True,
            validation_data=(X_test, X_test),
            callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/autoencoder')])
```

Comment: Please share the complete code and full stack trace of error. Sample data to duplicate the behaviour will also help.

Comment: is this enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_shape)
```

A shape is not a tensor.

Do this:

```
from keras.layers import *
inputTensor = Input(input_shape)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputTensor)
```

---

### Hint about autoencoders

You should separate the encoder and decoder as individual models. Later you will probably want to work with only one of them.

**Encoder:**

```
inputTensor = Input(input_shape)
x = ....
encodedData = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

encoderModel = Model(inputTensor,encodedData)
```

**Decoder:**

```
encodedInput = Input((4,4,8))
x = ....
decodedData = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

decoderModel = Model(encodedInput,decodedData)
```

**Autoencoder:**

```
autoencoderInput = Input(input_shape)
encoded = encoderModel(autoencoderInput)
decoded = decoderModel(encoded)

autoencoderModel = Model(autoencoderInput,decoded)
```

Comment: inputTensor = Input(input_shape)
        error:- Input name undefined

Comment: `from keras.layers import *`

Comment: autoencoder_model = Model(input_shape, decoded) error- ValueError: The list of inputs passed to the model is redundant. All inputs should only appear once. Found: [128, 128, 3] any suggestions

Comment: Again, it's not `input_shape`, it's `autoencoderInput`.

Comment: autoencoder_model.fit      error-ValueError: Error when checking target: expected model_2 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (300, 1)
autoencoder_model.fit   error-

Comment: An autoencoder has the output equal to the input, you should not be using classes or Y there. It's only `x_train` and `x_train`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973653/preparation-of-annoted-images-for-faster-rcnn any suggestions ?